# Rails contact form alignments

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

So I have this contact form in rails

```
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :email %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :email %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :phone %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :phone %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :description %><br />
      <%= f.text_area :description, :size=>"30x3" %>
    </div> <br/>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

I want my form to utilize full page, i.e. I want the fields till phone to be on the left side and the description as a text area on the right horizontally.

Something like [this](http://i57.tinypic.com/fy3eae.png)

I am using bootstrap with the rails.

I tried with col-md-4 for 1 part and col-md-8 for another. doesn't fix that. 
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this template i made here:

http://www.bootply.com/XAMvtjjoQw

You can adapt it to ruby like this:

```
<form>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>      
    <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <%= f.text_field :email, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <%= f.text_field :phone, :class => "form-control" %>
  </div>
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
    <%= f.text_area :description, :class=>"form-control", :size=>"30x3" %>

  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'
....append= ( f.text_field :name :class=>"form-control"

getting this error..


Also, I am not using form, I am using scaffold to generate that for me..

Comment: there is a coma missing in between the name of field and class reference

Comment: Damn! I need to be more concentrating I believe. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

for a pure HTML layout you can do this:

```
<form action='' method='post'>

<div class='row'>

    <div class='col-md-2'>

        <div class='control-group'>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input id="name" type='text' name='name' value='' class='form-control'>
        </div>

        <div class='control-group'>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input id="email" type='text' name='email' value='' class='form-control'>
        </div>

        <div class='control-group'>
            <label for="phone">Phone</label>
            <input id="phone" type='text' name='phone' value='' class='form-control'>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class='col-md-10'>

        <div class='control-group'>
            <label for="description">Description</label>
            <textarea id="description" name='description' class='form-control' rows='4'></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class='control-group'>
            <br><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' class='btn btn-sm btn-info'>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>  

</form>
```